# Increase FPS for object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow

Main Program

```
# In[10]:
cap = FileVideoStream('london_piccadilly_circus.mp4').start()
fps = FPS().start()

with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
    while True:
      ### for webcam ###
      image_np = cap.read()

      # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
      image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
      image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
      # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
      boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
      # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
      # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
      scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
      classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
      num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
      # Actual detection.
      (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
          [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
          feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
      print("Finish Actual Detection")

      # Visualization of the results of a detection.
      vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np,
          np.squeeze(boxes),
          np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
          np.squeeze(scores),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          line_thickness=8)
      print("Finish Visualization")

      ### for webcam ###
      cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np, (300,300)))
      if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cap.stop()
        break

      fps.update()

fps.stop()
print("[INFO] elasped time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
print("[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))
```

FileVideoStream Program for multithreading

```
class FileVideoStream:
    def __init__(self, path, queueSize=128):
        # initialize the file video stream along with the boolean
        # used to indicate if the thread should be stopped or not
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
        self.stopped = False

        # initialize the queue used to store frames read from
        # the video file
        self.Q = Queue(maxsize=queueSize)
        print("FileVideoStream Initialized.")

    def start(self):
        # start a thread to read frames from the file video stream
        t = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        # keep looping infinitely
        while True:
            # if the thread indicator variable is set, stop the
            # thread
            if self.stopped:
                return

            # otherwise, ensure the queue has room in it
            if not self.Q.full():
                # read the next frame from the file
                (grabbed, frame) = self.stream.read()

                # if the `grabbed` boolean is `False`, then we have
                # reached the end of the video file
                if not grabbed:
                    self.stop()
                    return

                # add the frame to the queue
                self.Q.put(frame)
            print("Queue size {}".format(self.Q.qsize()))
            print("Pass")

    def read(self):
        # return next frame in the queue
        return self.Q.get()

    def more(self):
        # return True if there are still frames in the queue
        return self.Q.qsize() > 0

    def stop(self):
        # indicate that the thread should be stopped
        self.stopped = True
```

I am trying to increase my FPS for object detection. I am using Tensorflow API to do detection. I have also followed this guide(https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/06/faster-video-file-fps-with-cv2-videocapture-and-opencv/) which uses threading to try to increase FPS. The main program and filevideostream code are shown above. I am getting a FPS of less than 1. From what i observe, the visualization and actual detection is so slow compared to the filevideostream thread feeding the frames. This results in lags. How do I increase FPS so that the frames can be shown more smoothly (real-time)?

Thank you very much

Comment: removing iamshow, if you can, will increase your FPS

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you can try:

- Make sure you're running TensorFlow with GPU enabled, if you have a compatible graphics card in your machine.
- If you're running on the CPU, [enable Intel's MKL](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide#tensorflow_with_intel_mkl_dnn) for x86 speedups.

You can find a lot more general advice on improving performance at https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide